# Mouse look not working in UPBGE

Tags: game-engine, 3d-mouse

[image]

I'm trying to make my first person character, and im using the mouse to interact with the view, but im using the logic brick and when i start my game, it doesn't work, nothing happen, what should i do?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

[image: mouse look in UpBGE]

You need to click the small arrow in the mouse sensor so that the movement is tracked every frame!